# Why does the For loop produce variable list length

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I need the following code when executed to produce a list with a fixed length of 4 elements.
Why doesn't it work with the for loop?

```
from random import choice

pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = []

for pulled_ticket in range(4):
    pulled_ticket = choice(pool)
    
    if pulled_ticket not in winning_ticket:
        winning_ticket.append(pulled_ticket)

print(winning_ticket)
```

When I execute the code, the results look something like this:

```
[7, 4, 8, 'e']

[5, 'e']

['e', 6, 3]
```

But with the while loop, I don't have this problem:

```
from random import choice

pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = []

while len(winning_ticket) < 4:
    pulled_ticket = choice(pool)
    
    if pulled_ticket not in winning_ticket:
        winning_ticket.append(pulled_ticket)

print(winning_ticket)
```

The list length is always four:

```
['e', 5, 1, 8]

[7, 'd', 2, 8]

[2, 6, 'e', 10]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use `choices`?

Comment: Your first example sometimes hits the same number, hence why the if condition doesnt go through.

Comment: And the 2nd example will keep iterating until the reached len is 4. While the for only executes 4 times.

Comment: You can just use `winning_ticket = random.sample(pool, 4)` instead.

Comment: When you use a `for` loop, surely you have a certain number of loops (in your case, you'll have 4 loops), but when you use `while` loop and you are forcing the while to run until a list reaches a certain length, the while runs til that point. So, `for` loop is **less likely** to give you a list with 4 elements.

Comment: Your for loop makes 4 choices. Your while loop *keeps on* choosing until you have 4 *distinct* results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is like I stated in the comments, Your for loop only always does 4 iterations. While your while loop goes on till the reached length is 4.

Example output:

```
Iteration: 1
Iteration: 2
Iteration: 3
Iteration: 4
[4, 8, 'a']
Iteration: 1
Iteration: 2
Iteration: 3
Iteration: 4
Iteration: 5
Iteration: 6
[9, 6, 'a', 'b']
```

You can see that the for loop gives you a 3 size list while doing 4 passes, meaning once it hit the same random number.
A way easier way to do this could be so simply use choices, Like @norie, bc you can specify the size of the returning list and there is no need for loops.

```
print(choices(pool, k=4))
['a', 8, 'd', 8]
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense! Thanks a lot! I am still new to this, next time I'll be sure to use @norie 's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer it pretty logical
when using `for pulled_ticket in range(4):` you are going to trigger the `choice` and then `if` *4* times, if you pick the same number twice it will not be added and you will finish with *3* items in the list

the `while loop` **waits** for there to be 4 items so if it gets the same choice multiple times it will just continue

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! Now it's clear.